# In MySQL, How would I go about comparing todays date vs. a date in my database table?

Tags: php, mysql, date, extjs

I am building a web app for pregnant women (for my college web development course)
and in my database I have each users conception date stored.

In my application I take the conception date and compare it to today and give the user a little bit of information about that point in their pregnancy.

I have a table in my database also that holds a record for each "Stage" of the pregnancy *(i.e. Stage 1 = 1-2months, Stage 2 = 2-3months etc.)*
So how would I structure my MySQL query? This is what I have been trying to work with...

```
SELECT s.id as stageid
  , p.id as patientid
  , s.name
  , s.nutritioninfo
  , s.commonsymptoms
  , p.conceptiondate 
FROM stage s, patient p 
WHERE p.id=? AND TO_DAYS(p.conceptiondate)=To_DAYS(NOW());,
```

The last line (the `TO_Days()=TO_DAYS()` part) above is the part where I am struggling.
 Would it be wise to store a row for start date and end date for each stage in my "Stage" table?
But then how would that work since all of my users will have separate conception dates?

I will be using this query in php and then using that PHP query inside my interface that is built in ExtJS.

Comment: Stages should likely be 1-3 months, 4-6 months, and 7-9 months. These are generally referred to as "trimesters" in the human pregnancy world.

Comment: @MJB I'm sure the OP meant to ask 'bout SQL, not biology LOL

Comment: @Johan: yeah, I know. But writing a good app means knowing your audience, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT s.id as stageid
  , p.id as patientid
  , s.name
  , s.nutritioninfo
  , s.commonsymptoms
  , p.conceptiondate 
FROM stage s, patient p 
WHERE p.id=? and TO_DAYS(p.conceptiondate)=To_DAYS(NOW());,
```

Has a couple of issues:

1. Don't use the implicit join syntax (joins using where), it is confusing and depreciated; **always use explicit joins!** see below.
2. Nowhere in your query is there a join criterion where a field from `stage s` is joined to a field from `patient p`, e.g. *`(join on p.x = s.y)`*
3. I would recommend against using single days in your stage database. Use ranges rather replacing field `stage.stageday` with 2 fields `stage.startday` and `stage.endday`

Here's my suggestion:

```
SELECT s.id as stageid
 , p.id as patientid
 , s.name
 , s.nutritioninfo
 , s.commonsymptoms
 , p.conceptiondate 
FROM patient p
INNER JOIN stage s 
  ON (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), p.conceptiondate) BETWEEN s.startday AND s.endday)
WHERE p.id=?
```

This uses an explicit join [cf ANSI 92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) syntax, which clearly shows how the two tables are joined.
I've added two new fields `startday` and `endday`, now you need only to define 1 row per phase in the pregnancy. You can even have overlapping phases.
0 = the day of conception, 196 should be the day of birth. Don't forget to include sufficient extra days in case of a late birth :-).

Comment: Thanks times a million! We haven't really gone too in depth with MySQL in my webdev course, so I haven't ever gotten a chance to learn about implicit and explicit joins, but I will definitely take a dive into reading about them. Thanks again! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

I would not hold actual "dates" in the staging table, but start and stop DAYs... Ex: first month would be from day 0 to day 30... Second month from day 31 to day 60, etc.

Then, your query can query where the (psuedo syntax)

```
current_date() between Conception + Stage.StartDays 
                   and Conception + Stage.StopDays
```

in MySQL, its syntax would be

```
date_add( Conception, interval Stage.StartDays day ) as an example.
```

This way, one person conceiving on Jan 1 would be in month 4, yet someone conceiving yesterday would be in the first month (or zero depending on how "months" are classified).